# Sum of node and parents (sparse table)

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I need to calculate the sum of a given node and a number of parents ex: node 2 and 5 parents and l have to return the sum of the values of that nodes.

I calculate the sparse table with the k^j ancestros but i dont how to calculate the sum. The problem is that i dont kwon how with the binary Lifting sum all the parents nodes I have to sum.

```
class sumKnodes {
    vector<vector<int> > sTable; 
    vector<int> depth;  
    vector<vector<int> > adjacencyList;
    std::vector<int> values;
    int LOG;

public:

sumKnodes(int N) : adjacencyList(N) {}

void preProcess(int N) {
    LOG = 0;
    while((1 << LOG) <= N) {
        LOG++;
    }

    sTable = vector<vector<int> >(N, vector<int>(LOG, -1));
    depth = vector<int>(N, 0);
    

    dfs(0, 0);
    depth[0] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < LOG; j++) {
            sTable[i][j] = sTable[ sTable[i][j -1]][j - 1];
        }
    }

}


void addValue(int value) {
    values.push_back(value);
}


void addEdge(int u, int v) {
    adjacencyList[v].push_back(u);
    adjacencyList[u].push_back(v);
}

void dfs(int node, int parent) {
    sTable[node][0] = parent;

    if (node > 0) {
        depth[node] = depth[parent] + 1;
    }

    for (int child : adjacencyList[node]) {
            if (child != parent) {
                dfs(child, node);
            }
        }


}


int query(int node, int parents) {
    //suma node mas su numero de parents obteniendo los indices de sTable
    //Y con ese indice sumar el valor de values

    if (parents > depth[node]) {
        parents = depth[node];
    }

    int sum = values[node];

        for (int j = LOG - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (parents >= (1 << j)) {
                if (parents%(1 << j) != 0) {
                    sum += values[sTable[node][j]] + values[sTable[sTable[node][j]][j]];
                    parents -= (1 << j);
                }  else {
                    sum += values[sTable[node][j]];
                    //parents -= (1 << j);
                }
                
            }
        }

        return sum;

}

};
```

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to learn C++ by competitive coding? Because with all respect your code very hard to read e.g. `sum += values[sTable[node][j]] + values[sTable[sTable[node][j]][j]];`)... it doesn't even come close to describing what you are doing. Good code should read like a recipe with clear steps with readable variable names or even calls to small readable functions. Do NOT worry about performance first (probably your compiler is going to do a good job anyway)

Comment: thanks for your comments but you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried out drawing a tree on paper? Or did actually make a tree datastructure?
If not create a Tree class with operations to get the parent of a node etc. (A node can be an index into a vector thats fine) and use that to build your algorithm. A bunch of standalone vectors is NOT a tree